# How should I debug

Tags: keras, nlp

```
    def clean_str(string):
        string = re.sub(r"\\", "", string)
        string = re.sub(r"\'", "", string)
        string = re.sub(r"\"", "", string)
        return string.strip().lower()

    input_data = pd.read_csv('E:\\data\\rawData\\labeledTrainData.tsv', sep='\t')#导入数据

    for idx in range(input_data.review.shape[0]):
        text = BeautifulSoup(input_data.review[idx], features="html5lib")
        text = clean_str(text.get_text().encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
        texts.append(text)
        sentences = tokenize.sent_tokenize(text)
        reviews.append(sentences)
        labels.append(input_data.sentiment[idx])
```

---

bug:

Using TensorFlow backend.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "e:/python程序库/wu.py", line 379, in <module>
        text = clean_str(text.get_text().encode('ascii', 'ignore'))
      File "e:/python程序库/wu.py", line 370, in clean_str
        string = re.sub(r"\\", "", string)
      File "C:\Users\29091\Anaconda3\lib\re.py", line 192, in sub
        return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `string` variable has to be a python unicode string, not a bytes object (assuming this is py3):

```
In [3]: re.sub(r"\'", "", "jack's")
Out[3]: 'jacks'

In [4]: re.sub(r"\'", "", b"jack's")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-0ca08a0c3ee4> in <module>()
----> 1 re.sub(r"\'", "", b"jack's")

~/miniconda3/envs/address/lib/python3.6/re.py in sub(pattern, repl, string, count, flags)
    189     a callable, it's passed the match object and must return
    190     a replacement string to be used."""
--> 191     return _compile(pattern, flags).sub(repl, string, count)
    192 
    193 def subn(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0):

TypeError: cannot use a string pattern on a bytes-like object

In [5]: re.sub(r"\'", "", b"jack's".decode())
Out[5]: 'jacks'
```

- the first call works
- adding a `b` prefix in the second example to turn the data into bytes produces the same error that you are seeing
- adding a call to `.decode` to turn the bytes into string fixes the error again